# Averaging coefficients obtained from linear models of infinite subset in regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning

If we estimate coefficients for a linear model by repeating experiments infinite
number of times (Which means collecting samples or datasets infinite number of times
and fitting a linear model for each such sample or dataset) and calculate the average
values of the coefficients obtained from the linear models of these experiments for each
variable, what can be said of these average values?

Will they be more or less or equal to true value of coefficients

Comment: Since the average is unbiased, the average of the coefficients (also averages) will be close to the population mean (assuming all else holds).

Comment: You might also use the median value rather than the mean (average) value.